# Ubuntu:- append remove keyword to a file

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a file containing file name.

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

I wan to create a shell script that add the'rm' infront

```
rm file1
rm file2
rm file3
rm file4
```

How to append the rm in front the file name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that many ways - `sed`, `vim`, `perl`, `awk`.

Or you can simply use `xargs` like this:

```
xargs rm < filelist
```

If you really insist on editing `filelist`, use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^/rm /g' filelist > newscript
```

(which means find start of line `^` and replace it with `rm` for every line `/g`).

You can even edit `filelist` in-place using `sed -i`:

```
sed -i 's/^/rm /g' filelist
```

Comment: sed 's/^/rm /g' filelist > newscript this is what I wanted, thank alot

Answer (score 1):

I think mvp's answer is the best, but if you're talking about *changing* your current file list to a shell script with `rm` inserted before each filename, you can do this simply with any good text editor that supports find and replace with regular expressions.

Search term : `^(.)`

Replacement : `rm \1`

Vi one-liner :

```
:%s/^/rm /
```

Comment: I am try to automate the process, my intention is write a cron job, this is the part of the script I wish to write

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using a simple shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$1

while read line
do
  echo "Removing $line"
  rm $line
done < $FILE
```

You could then run it as `sh multirm.sh filelist`

If you want to simply add `rm` in to the file you could use awk for that.

`awk '{ print "rm", $1" }' filelist`